# ASP.NET MVC 3 EF Code First - How do I make a model that optionally refers to a parent of its own type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to create a model that can optionally refer to a parent of the same type, for example:

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual long CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category? ParentCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

}
```

As you can see there is an optional member called ParentCategory that is optional and refers to a class of type Category (i.e. the same type). As I'm sure you can guess, I'm trying to create a simple Category tree, where the root node(s) will not have a parent.

This results in the following error when the Entity Framework tries to create the database:

*"The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'ParentCategoryID' on type 'MyProject.Models.Category' is not valid. The navigation property 'Category' was not found on the dependent type 'MyProject.Models.Category'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name."*

I also tried this:

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual long CategoryID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public virtual long? ParentCategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

}
```

But again this resulted in the same error.

Is it possible to model this using EF Code First? Its easy to model it int he database if I were to create the database manually.

Thanks in advance
Ben

Comment: Have you tried calling the property `Category`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example wouldn't even compile because `T?`, a shortcut for `Nullable<T>` can only be applied to value types.

The following works fine here:

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual long CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Now, this will use an ugly name by default for the FK, `ParentCategory_CategoryID`.

This is a way to get a nicer name, plus some flexibility when using it:

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual long CategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentCategoryID")]
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual long? ParentCategoryID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Diego. I notice that you have both a ParentCategory and ParentCategoryID field, but only the ID version is nullable. What happens for the root nodes in the tree where there is no parent? Obviously the ParentCategoryID will be set to NULL but what happens to ParentCategory?

Comment: Since ParentCategory is a reference type, it is nullable by default. So when a category has no parent category, ParentCategory will automatically be null.